# How to handle an excellent answer to not-quite-my-question?

Tags: discussion, answers

Still fairly new, need advice on this one:

@Jack Lesnie posted a [great answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/68788/23970) to [How do I, as a player, encourage more role-playing in Adventurers League?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68773/23970) Unfortunately, I think it's a great answer to the question *"How do I, as a player, encourage more role-playing?"* As well-written and useful as I find his suggestions, there's nothing in there that specifically addresses the challenges of AL play as opposed to any table.

I'd love to see his answer have a +25 and a green check next to it, but *as an answer to the question posed* I'm fighting the urge to downvote it.

- Should I create the question *"How do I, as a player, encourage more role-playing?"* and invite Jack to re-post his answer there?
- Should I edit the question to 'match' the answer(s), then separately re-ask my original question? (I don't think this does much harm to the two other answers, as one completely ignores the AL portion of the question, and the other makes one good AL-centric suggestion among a half-dozen others.)
- Or should I rather leave some comments to this effect and let it play out from there?

Answer (score 7):

Answers that don't help are, as the voting tooltip says, “not useful”. You don't need to fight the urge to downvote, as that is a perfectly acceptable way to indicate that there are problems with an answer. Remember that votes “unlock” and can be changed any time a post is edited.

You can leave a comment explaining the problem, too. Just don't get into an argument if the author doesn't agree that it's a problem. (And at this point, since the answer is now virtually guaranteed to not improve by your standards, a downvote is easily justified.)

An answer that would be good if only the question was different is still not a good answer to *that* question. If the answer is really, really good by some other standard, someone else can ask the question it matches and it can be posted there. Sometimes, the author of the answer itself might choose to do this, and post it as a self-answer. The point is, there's no need to “go easy” on an answer that you think is well-made but off-target, since it can (and maybe should) be submitted to a different question and allowed to prosper *there*. If the author wants everyone's upvotes and to avoid their downvotes, they need to hit the target.

(And remember that this doesn't have to be *objectively* true. People can disagree on an answer's usefulness and vote differently. A vote *needs* to be one's own judgement, so the site can average the different votes. Just worry about your own standards, not what your single vote should be “objectively.”)

Votes exist to sort the good answers *for that question* from the not-so-good, and put them in order from best to least-best. Vote early and often.

Answer (score 3):

The first step to improving someone else's answer to your question is a comment.  Comment on the answer and explain what could be done to improve it.  If you feel that there needs to be some attention given to specifically calling out AL issues, then say that in a comment.  In general, if your thought is "this answer is not as awesome as I'd like it to be", the right tool for the job is a comment.

Comment: Thanks--will do.